# JUnit & Powermock: Native Library already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dll, junit, powermock

I have some test classes that need to verify that GLFW-functions were called. But when I want to execute all tests in IntelliJ then I get the error:

```
Native Library lwjgl.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

I use Powermock to verify that the static methods have been called:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})
public class GlfwWindowImplTest {
    // ...
    @Test
    public void update_swapsBufferAndPollsEvents() {
        GlfwWindowImpl target = new GlfwWindowImpl(1L);
        mockStatic(GLFW.class);

        target.update();

        verifyStatic();
        GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(1L);
        verifyStatic();
        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})
public class GlfwWindowSystemImplTest {
    // ...
    @Test(expected = GlfwInitializeException.class)
    public void initialize_throwsExceptionIfGlfwInitFails() {
        GlfwWindowSystemImpl target = new GlfwWindowSystemImpl();
        mockStatic(GLFW.class);
        when(GLFW.glfwInit()).thenReturn(GL_FALSE);

        target.initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: `@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})` ammend the class and load it in new classloader.

Comment: @Exhauzt Did you ever get a solution to this problem? I can't understand what the solution below is telling you to do. Your original code already seems to have  `@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})`... so what did you have to do differently? Thank you

Comment: No, I actually didn't find a solution but a had to do another project shortly after... So I didn't dig too much in this topic to find a solution. And I don't understand that solution as well

Answer (score 4):

It may be a bit late to answer this post, but I ran into a similar problem and I was able to solve it with PowerMock.  PowerMock has **@SuppressStaticInitializationFor** that should help you overcome this issue. Section **Suppress static initializer** in the link below has a nice example about how to do that:

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior

Basically, in your case, there could be a class that is calling **System.loadLibrary("lwjgl")**.  You need to locate that class. Example:

```
public class SomeClass {
    ...
    static {
        System.loadLibrary ("lwjgl");
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your test class use **@SuppressStaticInitializationFor** with the fully qualified name of the class:

```
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.example.SomeClass")
```

If in case the class doing the loadLibrary call is an inner class, then you need to add **$InnerClass** to fully qualify the inner class. Example:

```
public class SomeClass {
    ...
    public static class SomeInnerClass {
        static {
            System.loadLibrary ("lwjgl");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you need to use:

```
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.example.SomeClass$SomeInnerClass")
```

Comment: It's never too late!

Comment: @RichardT Would nice to have an example code snippet showing usage of  **@SuppressStaticInitializationFor**

Answer (score 1):

`@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})` loads the ClassLoader for the native library `lwjgl.dll` which is already loaded in the ClassLoader.

You can use the `@PowerMockIgnore` to defer the loading of classes with the names supplied to value() to the system ClassLoader.

For example suppose you'd like to defer the loading of all classes in the org.myproject package and all its sub-packages but you still like to prepare "MyClass" for test. Then you do like this:

```
 @PowerMockIgnore("org.myproject.*")
 @PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 public class MyTest {
 ...
 }
```

[JavaDoc Reference](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PowerMockIgnore.html)

Answer (score 0):

`@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})` create new `ClassLoader` and load ammended class in it. I suspect that `GLFW` load `lwjgl` library in its static initializer section.

You can try to unload library, but I don't know what consequences it may lead to.

I suggest wrap `GLFW` and use that wrapper in your applicatin.

Comment: This is a very confusing answer. Are you saying the solution is `@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})` ? That's what his original code already has. What does it look like to `wrap GLFW and use that wrapper in your application` like you said? Please clarify :)

Comment: `@PrepareForTest({GLFW.class})` is not solution, but cause of problem. It lead to reloading class. Reloaading of class lead to execution of static section and executing static section lead to second load of `lwjgl.dll` library.