# Native Library D:\jdk 1.8.0 181\jre1.8.0_181\bin\glass.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, exception, javafx, powermock, testfx

My problem is when I use Powermock with ApplicationTest or GuiTest. I gives  Native Library D:\jdk 1.8.0 181\jre1.8.0_181\bin\glass.dll already loaded in another classloader. So I have to show stage without using ApplicationTest or GuiTest. Or is there a solution for this. I try https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html solutions but it is not solved my problem. I can't run my unittest.

```
public class AlertMessagesTest extends TestFXGuiBase{
    @Test
    public void setMessage() throws Exception {
        Platform.runLater(() -> AlertMessages.setMessage(AlertMessages.AlertMessagesType.NAME, ""));
        functions.sleep(1000);
        functions.clickOn("Ok");
    }}
```

```
public class AreaController extends SystemAdministrationManagement {  

static {
    System.loadLibrary ("glass.dll");
}

public void loadAreaManagement() throws Exception {
    super.addSearchIconToTextField(filterText);

    setVersion();

    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    filteredData = new FilteredList(getData(), p -> true);

    addAreaNadModeListToTableView();
}
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Database.class, AlertManager.class, AreaController.class})
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("gov.sysadmin.areaManagement.AreaController")
public class AreaControllerTest extends TestFXGuiBase {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/areaManagement/area.fxml"));

    @Test
    public void showAreaNadModeListTestFunction() throws Exception{
        TrainLine trainLine = new TrainLine();
        trainLine.setId(1);
        trainLine.setName("Name");
        trainLine.setExp("Explanation");

        Area firstArea = new Area();
        firstArea.setId(1);
        firstArea.setShortname("BSM");
        firstArea.setLongname("BSM");
        firstArea.setTrainline(1);
        firstArea.setOrderno((byte) 1);
        firstArea.setAddressxml(null);
        firstArea.setAreaxml(null);
        firstArea.setExplanation("BSM");
        firstArea.setTrainlineByTrainline(trainLine);
        firstArea.setIsautonad(false);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date secondAreaDayStartTime = dateFormat.parse("08:00:00");
        Date secondAreaNightStartTime = dateFormat.parse("21:00:00");

        Area secondArea = new Area();
        secondArea.setId(2);
        secondArea.setShortname("BND");
        secondArea.setLongname("BND");
        secondArea.setTrainline(1);
        secondArea.setOrderno((byte) 2);
        secondArea.setAddressxml(null);
        secondArea.setAreaxml(null);
        secondArea.setExplanation("");
        secondArea.setTrainlineByTrainline(trainLine);
        secondArea.setDaystart(new Time(secondAreaDayStartTime.getTime()));
        secondArea.setDaystart(new Time(secondAreaNightStartTime.getTime()));
        secondArea.setIsautonad(true);

        List<Area> areaList = new ArrayList<Area>();
        areaList.add(firstArea);
        areaList.add(secondArea);

        PowerMock.suppressConstructor(Database.class);
        PowerMock.mockStatic(Database.class);
        Database mockDatabase = EasyMock.createMock(Database.class);
        EasyMock.expect(Database.getInstance()).andReturn(mockDatabase).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.expect(mockDatabase.getAllArea()).andReturn(areaList);
        EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(1);
        PowerMock.replay(Database.class);
        PowerMock.replay(mockDatabase);

        AreaController areaNadModeListController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        AreaController spy = Mockito.spy(areaNadModeListController);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).setVersion();
        spy.loadAreaManagement();

        EasyMock.verify(mockDatabase);
    }
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\jdk 1.8.0 181\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\glass.dll already loaded in another classloader

    at org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils.waitFor(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:284)
    at org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.waitForLaunch(FxToolkit.java:323)
    at org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.registerPrimaryStage(FxToolkit.java:132)
    at org.testfx.framework.junit.ApplicationTest.internalBefore(ApplicationTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:129)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:93)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\jdk 1.8.0 181\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\glass.dll already loaded in another classloader
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\jdk 1.8.0 181\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\glass.dll already loaded in another classloader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1907)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:112)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:120)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:40)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$1.run(WinApplication.java:104)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$1.run(WinApplication.java:90)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.<clinit>(WinApplication.java:90)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:36)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    ... 5 more
```

First one is my class. Second one is my test class of AreaController class and the last one is the exception.

Comment: does anyone have any idea about the solution ?

Comment: Please have a look at this question: [JUnit & Powermock: Native Library already loaded in another classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248363/junit-powermock-native-library-already-loaded-in-another-classloader)

Comment: I try them but not solve my problem.

Comment: So after applying the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083279/2378429), does it give a different exception? If not, please share some code, it is hard to say what is wrong just from the stack trace. My guess would be you somehow misapplied the annotation, but without seeing the code I cannot help you.

Comment: And in your test class you used `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("AreaController")` (with the appropriate package prepended, of course)?

Comment: I editted question and add some part of code and test.

Comment: @SuppressStaticInitializationFor("gov.sysadmin.areaManagement.AreaController") I added with the appropriate package prepended

Comment: Have you tried removing `AreaController.class` from `@PrepareForTest({})`?

Comment: I have removed AreaController.class from @PrepareForTest but continue to give the same error. I updated the question. I have added the AlertMessagesTest class. 
The AlertMessagesTest test class is running and the AreaController class is called after AlertMessagesTest and the first function returns an error.

Comment: Is there any other class that is referencing `AreaController`? By doing so, it could cause the class to be loaded prematurely (before Powermock has a chance to suppress the static initialization).

Comment: There is no other class that references AreaController. With your suggestion, I've also put @ SuppressStaticInitializationFor before @ RunWith and I've put it before @PrepareForTest but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas then. Hope you find the solution. When you do, post it as an answer :)

Comment: does anyone have any idea about the solution ?